# dynamic text on <p> tag from <select> tag attr

Tags: jquery

I got a lot of help from the site on the codes below, I hope its not to much to ask another (maybe another after this :))

Anyways, I looking at adding a text of a `<p>` tag, from an attribute in `<select>` tag, but I could seems to figure it out. below are the code:

```
HTML
<select id="AD">
    <option label="Fruits" id="Fruits1" value="Good for you">   </option>
    <option class="hide" id="Apples" value="http://www..."></option>
    <option class="hide" id="Orages" value="http://www..."></option>

    <option label="Chocolate" id="Chocolate1" value="Very Sweet"></option>
    <option class="hide" id="Hersheys" value="http://www...">
    <option class="hide" id="Kitkat" value="http://www..."></option>

    <option label="Planets" id="Planet1" value="One day we will live there"></option>
    <option class="hide" id="Mars" value="http://www..."></option>
    <option class="hide" id="Jupiter" value="http://www..."></option>

    <option label="Softdrinks" id="Softdrinks" value="Lots of sugar"></option>
    <option class="hide" id="Coke" value="http://www...">
    <option class="hide" id="Pepsi" value="http://www..."></option>
</select>

<div>
    <p id="iframeId"></p>
</div>
<div>
    <iframe id="iframeId1" scr=""></iframe>
</div> 
<div>
    <iframe id="iframeId2" scr=""></iframe>
</div>

JQUERY Code
$(document).ready(function() {                      
    $("#AD").change(function() {
        $('#iframeId').attr('src', $(this).find('option:selected').val());
        $('#iframeId1').attr('src', $(this).find('option:selected').next().val()); 
        $('#iframeId2').attr('src', 
        $(this).find('option:selected').next().next().val());   
    });
    $("#AD").change(); 
});
```

The iframes work just fine, just could not have the `<p>` tag show. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting a `src` attribute on a `p` tag which is incorrect and will do nothing.
You can set the text of the `p` tag by using `text()`

```
$('#iframeId').text($(this).find('option:selected').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding Musa's answer with a working example, setting `text()` instead of the incorrect `src` attribute definitely does the job.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#AD").change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');

    $('#iframeId').text(selected.val());
    $('#iframeId1').attr('src', selected.next().val());
    $('#iframeId2').attr('src', selected.next().next().val());
  });
  $("#AD").change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="AD">
  <option label="Fruits" id="Fruits1" value="Good for you"> </option>
  <option class="hide" id="Apples" value="http://www..."></option>
  <option class="hide" id="Orages" value="http://www..."></option>

  <option label="Chocolate" id="Chocolate1" value="Very Sweet"></option>
  <option class="hide" id="Hersheys" value="http://www..."></option>
  <option class="hide" id="Kitkat" value="http://www..."></option>

  <option label="Planets" id="Planet1" value="One day we will live there"></option>
  <option class="hide" id="Mars" value="http://www..."></option>
  <option class="hide" id="Jupiter" value="http://www..."></option>

  <option label="Softdrinks" id="Softdrinks" value="Lots of sugar"></option>
  <option class="hide" id="Coke" value="http://www..."></option>
  <option class="hide" id="Pepsi" value="http://www..."></option>
</select>

<div>
  <p id="iframeId"></p>
</div>
<div><iframe id="iframeId1" scr=""></iframe></div>
<div><iframe id="iframeId2" scr=""></iframe></div>
```